# Odd behavior with SQLite3 non-SELECT prepared transactions and fetchArray()

Tags: php, sqlite, prepared-statement

I ran into an odd issue earlier today which had me stumped for a while: I was doing precisely *one* transaction (confirmed umpteen different ways), and yet I was adding *two* elements to my SQLite3 database.

Finally twigged as to the possible cause, and tracked it down.

Here's a very minimal testcase which I've written to be as simple and straightforward as possible:

```php
<?php

function dostuff($f) { 
    @unlink($f);
    $db = new SQLite3($f);
    $db->exec('CREATE TABLE test (a TEXT)');
    $s = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO test (a) VALUES (:a)');
    $s->bindValue(':a', 'OHI');
    return $s->execute();
}

$f = '__test1__.sqlite3';
dostuff($f);

system('sqlite3 '.$f.' .dump');

print "\n---------------------\n\n";

$f = '__test2__.sqlite3';
$r = dostuff($f);

while (($row = @$r->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) !== false) {
    print "LOOP EXECUTED!\n";
}                   

system('sqlite3 '.$f.' .dump');

?>
```

Firstly, `dostuff` creates a new database, which is removed if it exists. Then I create a test table, set up a prepared transaction, run the prepared transaction, and then the function `return`s the `SQLite3Result` object from `$s->execute()`.

(I made a function for this code because it gets run twice, to keep the SLOC down.)

Here's what I understand is going on:

1. I run `dostuff()` with a first test file.
2. I run `dostuff()` with a second test file, but then I grab the `SQLite3Result` that the function returns, and then iterate over that as though I've just run a SELECT statement and I need to grab the results.

In both cases I dump the resulting database that's been created using `system(sqlite3 .dump)`, as this is a simple, effective way to dump DBs with well-known, predictable results, and I wanted to avoid writing my own potentially buggy code.

This is the output I get on my machine, with PHP 7.0.5 and SQLite3 3.12.0 (PHP module version 0.7):

```sql
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE test (a TEXT);
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES('OHI');
COMMIT;

---------------------

PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE test (a TEXT);
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES('OHI');
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES('OHI');
COMMIT;
```

Note that my code contains a loud "LOOP EXECUTED" line inside the `fetchArray()` loop, but this isn't showing up. The only output that is being presented is the output of the `system()` calls and the `print` statement displaying the dashes.

I crashed into this as I was building a DB helper class that would run statements for me and handle retrieving the results (my queries return very very small result sets so gathering all of them simplifies everything with no cost).

I've now written prepared-statement `query()` and `exec()` functions that do and do not try to fetch a result set, respectively - now I just have to remember to use the right ones in the right places!

**TL;DR: `INSERT` + `fetchArray()` runs the query twice.**

**My question: Is this a bug?** Or is it known behavior in SQLite3?

Comment: ...I need to Google better. **YES, KNOWN (OPEN) BUG in PHP, reported here**: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64531 - note the `$res->numColumns()` at the end, that fixes it.